# How can I turn this into a human readable output?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, events, confirmations

I have this buy function but the output gives me a transaction Nr. or whatever this is

```
async function buy() {
  var a = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log(accounts);
  var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);

  contract.methods.buy(a, "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000").send(
    {from:accounts[0]},
    function(error, approve){
      if(error){
        console.log(error)
      } else if(approve){
        console.log("you bought :" + approve)
      }
  });
};
```

And this is the output:

```
You bought  :0x54c06a7af7a1a4d9fbe4c69778ea23f40514029124674d86225bec14ae0494d8
```

how can i trn this into readable out put like, you bought xxx amount of token, for example?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the nasty comment that this dude has made in a comment to the highly elaborated and well explained answer that he was given. There are plenty similar questions around the same issue, which is covered pretty thoroughly on this website, so there's no additional contribution in this one (let alone the fact that the question itself is totally oblivious of the actual problem, which makes it "unsearchable" for this specific issue).

Comment: that is the transaction hash, and you need to read the emitted event of that function, if it has some

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

You can't. That's it.

**Better answer:**

The async flow has two steps.

1. You have a transaction receipt which is a unique identifier for what you sent. It hasn't been mined, only accepted.
2. It gets mined, and something happens.

You're outputting the response from step 1. For step 2, you have a few options and they are documented all over so I'll just give you some keywords.

To update the UI:

1. Listen/**wait for the mined transaction** using the transaction hash you have. Then inspect read-only function(s) to discover the transaction state now that the transaction actually did something.
2. **Listen/wait for an event**. The event logs are defined by `event` in the contract, and emitted by `emit`. You can filter and search those as well as actively listen and react to whatever happens, when it happens.

A common conceptual hurdle with this is neither option gives the external client access to `return(...);` values define in contract functions. Those are only available to other functions and other contracts.

Hope it helps.

Comment: no it doesnt help at all

Comment: Then post the contract source with `buy()` so a kind soul might recommend one of the two methods for step 2 and show you how to do it, in your case. It's clear you're missing a step.